# Where can I find the "survivor of the old war" in XCOM 2?

Tags: xcom-2

In XCOM 2, one of the preorder bonuses is that you "Instantly unlock a survivor of the old war as a recruit in your barracks." Apparently after they are recruited, you get access to a new  cosmetic armour. I preordered the game but I'm not sure where this person is or if I have already recruited them. Does anyone know how to find this person and what the unlock actually is?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The survivor of the old war is simply a regular, normal recruit, but wearing an XCOM Enemy Unknown outfit.  This is based of a [developer's tweet here](https://twitter.com/SolomonJake/status/642077033233817600):

[image: XCOM developer's tweet]

The soldier has a randomized name, will be equipped with "Resistance Warrior Kevlar Armor", and will have a unique bio, e.g.:

> A survivor of the old war, Min Ho was a ranking officer within X-Com when the organization fell. He is rumored to have survived the ill-fated pre-war X-Com operation later referred to as the "Kiryu-Kai Disaster".

[image: Survivor bio]
[image: Survivor aArmor]

Comment: I saw this, but it's been so long since I played Enemy Unknown that I can't remember what it should look like. Do you have a screenshot of the EU outfit or can you say what it's name is in the armor selection screen?

Comment: I accepted the answer but I'll add a bit more info that I found while digging around.

Comment: @Bonnici it looks like the [plain body armor](http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/xcom/images/b/b6/XCOM-EU_Soldiers_Class_-_Support.png/revision/latest?cb=20121109205926)